# Failed to determine the https port for redirect in Docker

Tags: linux, windows, docker, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to deploy an asp.net-core webapi service which is exposed from 80 port using:

```
docker run --rm -p 80:80 --name radicadorrest -it radicadorrest
```

error:

> warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>        No XML encryptor configured. Key {e60978fd-16bc-4ff2-8525-39b5d0c36be5} may be persisted to storage in  unencrypted form. Hosting environment: Production Content root path:
>   /app Now listening on: http://[::]:80 Application started. Press
>   Ctrl+C to shut down.
>
> warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
>        Failed to determine the https port for redirect. Application is shutting down...

I have tried using different ports but I get the same error.

Docker version:

> Client: Version:      17.09.1-ce
>   API version:  1.32
>   Go version:  go1.8.3
>   Git commit:   19e2cf6
>   Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:25:13 2017
>   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
>
> Server: Version:      17.09.1-ce
>   API version:  1.32 (minimum version1.12)
>   Go version:   go1.8.3
>   Git commit:   19e2cf6
>   Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:26:35 2017 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64  Experimental:false

I have also trying on Windows with the same result.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The two warnings are totally unrelated.

For the DataProtection warning, I recommend following the guidance presented [here on the official ASP.Net Core documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#persisting-keys-when-hosting-in-a-docker-container).  If you care to dig in deeper as to the relevant source code and decision, you can see this [relevant ASP.Net GitHub PR](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/pull/244).

For the https redirection warning, I recommend simply removing the https redirection policy from the `startup.cs` file which is typically defined via `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` unless you're actually using this policy for your container and in this case you'd need to actually [setup the certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#how-to-setup-a-developer-certificate-for-docker) and expose the HTTPS port on your container.

Answer (score 19):

This is because when you created the ASP.NET Core project you selected the option "Configure for HTTPS". This adds the HttpsRedirectionMiddleware middleware which enforces SSL connections for your web app. The docker file you created is only specifying the HTTP port. Hence the HttpsRedirectionMiddleware is failing and shutting down the application. Basically if you had not selected the "Configure for HTTPS" option while you created the project you would be fine or ensure the SSL is setup properly (ports and certs).

Comment: That was my problem, when I removed "app.UseHttpsRedirection()" from "Startup/Configure" I managed to access, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be more by-the-book to keep the HTTPS redirection and enable Docker to work on a secure protocol? Or is it waaay to complicated to be rewarding?

Answer (score -4):

Your port only specifies http protocol not https you might have to find a way to have the docker to only look 80 and ignore 443 port which is for https